# bash: -c: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: loops, csv, if-statement, ssh

I'm trying to write this script
It's read variables from csv file and make SSH connections thourgh these variables and then run an if condition inside the SSH.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ------------------------------------------
INPUT=Mnt.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read rom alias port ver
do
ssh -n $alias "cd /opt/app;
               echo ========================================================
               find . -maxdepth 4 -type d -name '$rom' -print;
                echo $port;
                        if [ ${ver} -eq 'v3' ]
                        then
                        cat /opt/app/v3
                        elif
                        cat /opt/app/v2
                        fi
                        ;
               exit"

done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

It gives this error:

```
bash: -c: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: -c: line 9: `                        fi'
```

Please can you help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just corrected it like this anything work

```
"cd /opt/app;
               echo ========================================================
               find . -maxdepth 4 -type d -name '$rom' -print
                echo $port
                        if [ ${ver} = "v3" ]
                        then
                        cat /opt/app/v3
                        else
                        cat /opt/app/v2
                        fi
                        
               exit"
```